# mongoose $pull get nModified: 0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

After spending the whole day with that problem... i need help.

Node v12.14.1
mongoose v5.8.9
mongoDB v4.2.1

So everything is up to date.

I tried many ways, but this is how it should work:

```
model.updateOne({_id:model_id},{$pull: {videos: {_id:video_id},{multi:true})
```

but then i get

```
{ n: 1, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }
```

So, it get found, no errors but it dosent remove/modify the object.

Cant figure out what should be wrong.

Comment: I also forgott two }} in this example. The multi thing is just something i also tryed out. Also tryed with updateMany. I dont know how much possible combinations and answers from google and mongoose doc i've tryed for now.

Answer (score 0):

So from your query, I am assuming this is what your document looks like:

```
{
   _id: "<some uuid>",
   videos: [
      {
         _id: "<some uuid>"
      },
      {... n}
   ]
}
```

If that is the case, your update query looks good, and maybe you need to consider the video_id input.
Could you try the equivalent find?:

```
model.find({_id:model_id, 'team._id': video_id})
```

Comment: Yes, my doc looks like this.
And i can query the video object with
`model.findById(model_id,{'video._id':video_id})`
I really dont get i why $pull or .pull() will not work.
All the other CRUD functions are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes...
Sometimes the mistake took place way before we reach this line of code...

It was hard to find cause in terminal output and also in compass everything looks fine.

But, at that moment where i save the video and update the user to just have video id, title and slug also in the user collection, i did this:

```
$push: {
    videos: [{
        _id: data._id,
        title: data.title,
        slug: data.slug
    }]
}
```

Yes, i pushed an empty array containing an object into an array. But like i said, the output and also .find() was like everything is okay.

After i removed the [] brackets and tested a new data set, $pull works fine.

Guess this was my hardest bug... hardest bug till now!

Thanks for your helps!

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue but your object in an array bug is not the same as mine. my array is only a list of ObjectId so I could not understand why `{ n: 1, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }` is happening for me